# When WKWebView embed in a UITableViewCell, secondHalf of WebView will not display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, webview, wkwebview

This is very strange. I embed a WKWebView into the first cell(IndexPath.row = 0)of a UITableView . and if the webView's content is short ,it works fine.But when I put more text and image in the webView .the bottom part of the webView is not display. I have check the UI layer:
[image]
And I found the most upper layer(WKCompositingView) 's height is not right. the second layer is WKCompositingView too.

I don't know why,Buy if I put the WebView into a controller's view it worked fine.

Another point is , if I called a UITextFiled to first responder(call the keyboard out), than then webView will display normally。(but became 2 part   ,both WKCompositingView).
[image]
can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final ， I solved this question by adding [webViewCell setNeedsLayout] in the scrolldViewdidscroll method.

Answer (score 0):

I think, first cell not show out of content. You can add webview into view. After that, add this view into first cell. First cell will show out of content webview.